# CSS specificity on Font Awesome icon

Tags: css, sass

I am picking up my icon color from icon--apply instead of .classname__icon--apply. Doesn't this violate CSS specificity rules? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear of what the problem is? In both the cases icon--apply and .classname__icon--apply you have only one class that means both will have the same specificity value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing BEM with specificity.

Don't think of specificity like a set of rules, it's more like a mechanism. A mechanism which decides which rule should be more important than others.

> There's a whole bunch of selectors but for our purposes, we can break
>   it down into three types, of increasing importance:
>
> 1. Element selectors (and pseudo-element selectors) Eg. p {color:red;}
> 2. Class selectors (and attribute selectors) Eg. .myclass {color:red;}
> 3. ID selectors. Eg. #myid {color:red;}

https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c

BEM is a naming convention for your CSS classes. **You can decide** if you want to use it. It's optional.

> The Block, Element, Modifier methodology (commonly referred to as BEM)
>   is a popular naming convention for classes in HTML and CSS. Developed
>   by the team at Yandex, its goal is to help developers better
>   understand the relationship between the HTML and CSS in a given
>   project.

https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/

Another naming convention would be Atomic CSS, where you use a lot of small, single purpose classes - for example `.color-red`.
You can read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/lets-define-exactly-atomic-css/